# Solve for $n$ : $\lfloor{(n+1)\phi}\rfloor x + ny < z$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory, parametric, golden-ratio

Solve for the biggest value of $n$ such that :

$$\lfloor{(n+1)\phi}\rfloor x + ny < z$$

where $n$ is a positive integer , and $x,y,z$ are known parameters.

This problem arised when solving a computational problem . I tried to solve it and even plug it into wolfram alpha but with fail.

I want to find the number of element less than $Z$ in a given column of a [Wythoff Array](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/WythoffArray.html) . Is there any mathematical way to do it ?

Comment: A general formula looks quite difficult.

Comment: You do not wrote what is $\phi$.

Comment: @zkutch I presume $\phi$ must be the golden ratio

Comment: Are $x, y, z$ also positive integers?